# OpenMP slower than serial Fortran90 code

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, fortran90

In my Fortran90 code I have an outer cycle with several nested loops. In order to speed up my code, I tried to use OpenMP on the outer loop, but I have a very strange problem: when I use more than 1 thread the program runs slower than using OMP with 1 thread which is in turn slower than using the original serial program (in terms of wall clock time. I tried with 1, 2, 3 or 4 threads). In all the cases, however, I get the right result.

I conducted several tests on my code and at last I noticed that the problem is in one subroutine, because if I comment the call to that routine my parallel program works as expected, i.e. the bigger the number of threads, the lower the wall clock time.

Now, that routine takes in input 4 vectors, "ks1", "ks2", "ket1", "ket2" and performs the union between "ks1" and "ks2" obtaining "kstot". Then it creates 2 new vectors, "ket1tot" and "ket2tot", where ket1tot(i) is equal to ket1(j) if ks1tot(i) is equal to ks1(j), otherwise ket1tot(i)=0. The same for ket2tot.

Then combining the values stored in vectors "ks1tot", "ket1tot", "ket2tot" I compute which lines of a vector (matFC) contain the values I need and, by multiplication of that values, I obtain the final result (FCtot).

So I turn that routine in a simple program, adding some initial lines in order to mimic the real program. I mean I added:

1) a loop (on i) that mimics the outer loop of the real program I am trying to parallelize;

2) I implemented the fact that each thread works on a different file (so I should not have a false sharing problem)

3) I added another loop (on k) that mimics that I call the routine several times.

Here is the code (the part that constitutes the original subroutine that gives me problems is indicated in the text):

```
program evaluatefc
#ifdef _OPENMP
use omp_lib
#endif
implicit none   
integer::i,ii,j,jj,jjj,k,sizeks1,sizeks2,sizec,sizekstot,NR,NR1,maxnq
integer::line,ierr,fileunit,mythread,nfreqtot
real*8::FCtot,time1,time2
integer,allocatable,dimension(:)::ks1,ket1,ks2,ket2
integer,dimension(:),allocatable::c,kstot,ket1tot,ket2tot
real*8,allocatable,dimension(:)::matFC
character*15,allocatable,dimension(:)::matfileFC
character::fileFC*15
real*4::tstarting,tending
! This program was originally a subroutine 
! that takes in input 4 vectors, ks1, ks2, ket1, ket2
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! I initialize some values that in the original subroutine were computed by 
!the main program
allocate(matfileFC(3),stat=ierr)
matfileFC(1)='filea.dat'
matfileFC(2)='fileb.dat'
matfileFC(3)='filec.dat'
sizeks1=2
sizeks2=2
maxnq=11
allocate(ks1(sizeks1),stat=ierr)
allocate(ket1(sizeks1),stat=ierr)
allocate(ks2(sizeks2),stat=ierr)
allocate(ket2(sizeks2),stat=ierr)
nfreqtot=42
NR1=nfreqtot*(maxnq**2)+nfreqtot        
NR=nfreqtot*(maxnq**2)
allocate(matFC(NR),stat=ierr)
!Call two intrinsic to evaluate CPU and wall clock time
call cpu_time(time1)
tstarting=secnds(0.0)
!$OMP PARALLEL DO &
!$OMP DEFAULT(NONE) &
!$OMP firstprivate(sizeks1,sizeks2,maxnq,matfileFC,NR,NR1) &
!$OMP PRIVATE(i,ii,j,jj,k,ierr,mythread,fileunit,c,sizec,line,sizekstot) &
!$OMP PRIVATE(jjj,ket1,ks1,ket1tot,kstot,ket2,ks2,ket2tot,FCtot,matFC,fileFC)
do ii=1,3
   #ifdef _OPENMP
   mythread=OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
   #else
   mythread=10
   #endif
   fileFC=matfileFC(ii)
   ! Read some lines of a given file.
   fileunit=50+mythread
   open(unit=fileunit,name=fileFC,status='old',form='formatted')
   read(fileunit,*)!Do not read first line
   jjj=0
   do jj=1,NR1-1
       if(mod(jj,(maxnq**2+1)).eq.0) then
         read(fileunit,*)
       else
         jjj=jjj+1     
         read(fileunit,*)j,k,i,matFC(jjj)
   ! I actually need only the fourth valor of the line to be stored
       endif
   enddo
   close(fileunit)
   do k=1,10000000
       ! Again I initialize the abovementioned values that in the actual 
       ! subroutine are computed by the main program
       ks1(1)=mod(k,30)+1
       ks1(2)=mod(k,30)+2
       ks2(1)=mod(k,17)+1
       ks2(2)=mod(k,17)+3
       ket1(1)=mod(k,2)
       ket1(2)=mod(k,3)
       ket2(1)=mod(k,5)
       ket2(2)=mod(k,7)
       sizec=sizeks1+sizeks2
       allocate(c(sizec),stat=ierr)
       do i=1,sizeks1
           c(i)=ks1(i)
       enddo
       do i=sizeks1+1,sizec
          c(i)=ks2(i-sizeks1)
       enddo
       sizekstot=sizec
       do i=1,sizeks1
          do j=1,sizeks2
             if(ks1(i).eq.ks2(j)) then
               sizekstot=sizekstot-1
             endif
          enddo
       enddo
       allocate(kstot(sizekstot),stat=ierr)
       jjj=1
       i=1
       jj=0
       do i=1,sizec-1
           jjj=jjj+1
           do j=jjj,sizec
               if(c(i).eq.c(j)) then
                  exit   
               elseif(c(i).ne.c(j).and.j.eq.sizec) then
                  jj=jj+1
                  kstot(jj)=c(i)
               endif
           enddo
       enddo
       kstot(sizekstot)=c(sizec)
       allocate(ket1tot(sizekstot),stat=ierr)
       do i=1,sizekstot
           ket1tot(i)=0
       enddo
       allocate(ket2tot(sizekstot),stat=ierr)
       do i=1,sizekstot
           ket2tot(i)=0
       enddo
       do i=1,sizekstot
           do j=1,sizeks1
               if(kstot(i).eq.ks1(j))then
                  ket1tot(i)=ket1(j)
               endif
           enddo
       enddo
       do i=1,sizekstot
           do j=1,sizeks2
               if(kstot(i).eq.ks2(j))then
                     ket2tot(i)=ket2(j)
               endif
           enddo
       enddo
       FCtot=1
       do i=1,sizekstot
           line=(kstot(i)-1)*(maxnq)**2+ket1tot(i)*(maxnq)+ket2tot(i)+1
           FCtot=matFC(line)*FCtot
       enddo
       deallocate(c,stat=ierr)
       deallocate(kstot,stat=ierr)
       deallocate(ket1tot,stat=ierr)
       deallocate(ket2tot,stat=ierr)
   enddo
enddo
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
call cpu_time(time2)
tending=secnds(tstarting)
write(*,*)
write(*,*)'CPU time is:'
write(*,*)time2-time1
write(*,*)
write(*,*)'Wall clock time is:'
write(*,*)tending
end program
```

Still, I get the same problem, i.e. the wall clock time using 4 thread is bigger than using 1 thread.

For example I get (in seconds):

> type                 Wtime         CPU time
>
> 1 thread       20.37           20.37
>
> 4 thread       31.26           91.61
>
> serial         19.64           19.64

I am aware that the call to the OMP library introduces an overhead and in fact the 1-thread OMP program is slower than the serial one. But I cannot understand why the 4-thread OMP code is slower.

I use Intel fortran compiler 2013 on Linux.

Any suggestions?

Thank you for any time you can dedicate to this problem.

Comment: It would be much easier to read if you indent your code and show an small test program that represents what you are doing. Remember that you need help with OpenMP (and not with Theoretical Chemistry which many of us won't know much about) so this will allow us to help you better. That being said, have you tried to reorder the loops? Intel compiler is smart enough to "guess" which loop order is more convenient if it is sure enough that there isn't going to be any conflict. Also, try to move the allocate/deallocate outside the loops if possible, which is usually much more efficient.

Comment: @Jorge Bellón I'm sorry, I have now indented my code. About allocation/deallocation, in my real program ks1 etc. have not a fixed size, so I find useful to allocate every time with the right size. Anyway I have conducted a test, which shows that avoiding allocation/deallocation makes the code faster but does not fix the problem with OpenMP. Last, but not least, what do you mean "show a small test program"? The code I posted is a routine turned in a working code (if you have a file to be read like "filea.dat"), so I don't understand what is the "test program" I should post in your opinion.

Comment: Further to the previous comment, a compiler may skip redundant loop iterations when openmp is turned off.  Also, if running on hyperthreads you should be setting affinity if your openmp supports it.

Comment: `cpu_time()` is useless here. `system_clock()` is portable standard wall time subroutine (unlike secnds).

Comment: Your code is really long and the whole question as well. To long to read completely. Try to reduce both, the text (I already deleted something, but try to delete the physics stuff, it is not relevant) and the code. **We need much shorter code!** See [mcve]. If it does not fit into the box without scrolling, it is too long.

Comment: @Vladimir F I am sorry, this is my first post and I tried to do my best. I deleted something in the post, now I will try to reduce the code

Comment: @High Performance Mark. Thank you for your suggestions. I tried omp_get_wtime but it gave me the same results as secnds, so I used secnds. Anyway, I tried to parallelise the loop with shorter trip counts in order to give to each thread the most independent task I can in order to avoid false sharing.

Comment: You will need a way to find the hotspots in the code opin order to find a way to speed them up. Basically where and why.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed my own problem.

Thank you all for your suggestions, in particular @Jorge Bellón and @High Performance Mark.

As their comments said, the problem was actually the high number of allocation/deallocation. If I move the allocations out of the loops or at least if I put them right after the first loop, I get the "normal" OpenMP behaviour, i.e. the bigger the number of threads, the lower the wall clock time.

For the example above the wall clock time using 4 threads is now about 7 seconds.

Thank you all for your help.